# ASP.NET CORE. Reset all authentications

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to have all authentications reset after changing the user password. I tried to change security stamp, but it is don't reset authentications:

```
await _userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(User);
```

I am using Asp Net Core Identity.

Comment: What do you mean by resetting authorizations? Typically a password change just *changes the password*, so next time they sign in they have to put that instead. Could you try to clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: @juunas When a user is authorized from two devices. If the user changes the password on one device, must be reset authorization on the other device. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You mean *authentication* :) That's fine. Your question is really about how to sign out a user across devices/sessions.

Answer (score 0):

We do this on logout:

```
await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

But when users change their password, we don't need to log out only clear down the session or other persisted user context info, or re-create that info.

Comment: It does not work: InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: Cookies

Comment: This assumes you are using await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(..) and have this configured in the Startup using the same scheme.

Comment: e.g.: services.AddAuthentication(options => options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

Comment: I am using Auth0, but if the OP has an existing Login/Logout system working and needs to update the logged in user based on user information being updated, or re-authorize, the concept is to just re-authorize (reload the claims/permissions context info) or logout then then the user.